# Add signature pades-epes signature-policy-identifier attribute with iTextsharp (5.5.8)

Tags: itext, digital-signature, pades

I am currently evaluating iTextSharp (5.5.8) for a business case that includes pdf signing. The signature must include the pades-epes signature-policy-identifier attribute. I cannot find documentation and or samples to include this attribute. So the question I have is, is iTextSharp capable of providing this attribute and if so how can it be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope won't be too late, but I added some changes to iTextSharp source code to support PAdES-EPES signatures. Here are an example of my code:

```
        SignaturePolicyInfo spi = new SignaturePolicyInfo();
        spi.PolicyIdentifier = "2.16.724.1.3.1.1.2.1.9";
        spi.PolicyHash = "G7roucf600+f03r/o0bAOQ6WAs0=";
        spi.PolicyDigestAlgorithm = "SHA-1";
        spi.PolicyUri = "https://sede.060.gob.es/politica_de_firma_anexo_1.pdf";

        MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES, spi);
```

You can take a look at: https://github.com/zinkpad/itextsharp

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not show where in your code you got stuck.

If you are using `MakeSignature.SignDetached`, I'm afraid adding a policy identifier is not supported.

But you can always use `MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer` instead. This helper allows you to create the actual signature container to embed externally using e.g. BouncyCastle, so you can include any attribute you want while iText(Sharp) does all the rest.